# Stream Windows Webcam to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, streaming, directshow, mjpeg

I am attempting to stream video (no audio) from a Windows webcam  DirectShow to the iPhone browser. I am thinking that I will want to use VLC to transcode the video to an MJPEG stream over HTTP and open it in the browser.

I attempted to do this using this VLC command:
vlc -vvv dshow:// :sout=#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,vb=2000,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=mpjpeg,dst=192.168.1.178:8080/stream.mpjpg}}

When I attempt to open this stream in mobile Safari, I get the message "Safari cannot open file."

Does anyone have any suggestions for successfully streaming a webcam to the iPhone? I am looking for either suggestions for modifying the above code, or suggestions for software solutions that will preform this transcoding and streaming for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using ffserver and ffmpeg (http://ffmpeg.org/) for this.

```
# ffserver -f ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/webcam.ffm
```

starts the server. My ffserver.conf is

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -
NoDaemon
<Feed webcam.ffm>
  File /tmp/webcam.ffm
  FileMaxSize 50M
</Feed>

<Stream webcam.mjpeg>
  Feed webcam.ffm
  Format mpjpeg
  VideoSize qvga
  VideoFrameRate 15
  VideoBitRate 128
  VideoBufferSize 40000
  VideoQMin 1
  VideoQMax 10
  VideoIntraOnly
  Noaudio
  Strict -1
</Stream>
```

The mjpeg stream can be opened directly in safari, or embedded in a UIWebView if you are developing.